# Bootsnipp Step Wizard not rendering correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to learn Bootstrap / play around with Bootsnipp.

I have copied the HTML, CSS and JS from the link (although I think I have redundancy here): http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/e3MBM

1) Is it Redundant to add the CDN link and the actual CSS and JS (From what I understand the latter would only be if I host the CSS and JS files locally? Can someone confirm this?

2)The damn thing doesn't work the way it is supposed to:

[image: The BootSnipp One]

Is theirs - with each step shown separately.

Mine, on the other hand has everything together:
[image: Mine]

It's probably something so stupid and simple, but I have no idea.Can someone please help?

I tried JSFiddle *First time using it, looks easy, but I hope I've got it right :)

```
 <!DOCTYPE HTML>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vvstafo2/1/

Comment: Would you please check my answer\

Comment: I have done correction in your code, Now, Its working fine....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add bootstrap JS and CSS file thats why its conflict over there, Would you please once try with the below code?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var navListItems = $('div.setup-panel div a'),
          allWells = $('.setup-content'),
          allNextBtn = $('.nextBtn');

  allWells.hide();

  navListItems.click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var $target = $($(this).attr('href')),
              $item = $(this);

      if (!$item.hasClass('disabled')) {
          navListItems.removeClass('btn-primary').addClass('btn-default');
          $item.addClass('btn-primary');
          allWells.hide();
          $target.show();
          $target.find('input:eq(0)').focus();
      }
  });

  allNextBtn.click(function(){
      var curStep = $(this).closest(".setup-content"),
          curStepBtn = curStep.attr("id"),
          nextStepWizard = $('div.setup-panel div a[href="#' + curStepBtn + '"]').parent().next().children("a"),
          curInputs = curStep.find("input[type='text'],input[type='url']"),
          isValid = true;

      $(".form-group").removeClass("has-error");
      for(var i=0; i<curInputs.length; i++){
          if (!curInputs[i].validity.valid){
              isValid = false;
              $(curInputs[i]).closest(".form-group").addClass("has-error");
          }
      }

      if (isValid)
          nextStepWizard.removeAttr('disabled').trigger('click');
  });

  $('div.setup-panel div a.btn-primary').trigger('click');
});
```

```css
body {
    margin-top:40px;
}
.stepwizard-step p {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.stepwizard-row {
    display: table-row;
}
.stepwizard {
    display: table;
    width: 50%;
    position: relative;
}
.stepwizard-step button[disabled] {
    opacity: 1 !important;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100) !important;
}
.stepwizard-row:before {
    top: 14px;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    content: " ";
    width: 100%;
    height: 1px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    z-order: 0;
}
.stepwizard-step {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
}
.btn-circle {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 6px 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.428571429;
    border-radius: 15px;
}
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://bootsnipp.com/dist/bootsnipp.min.css?ver=7d23ff901039aef6293954d33d23c066">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://bootsnipp.com/dist/scripts.min.js"></script>
    <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  
<div class="stepwizard col-md-offset-3">
    <div class="stepwizard-row setup-panel">
      <div class="stepwizard-step">
        <a href="#step-1" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-circle">1</a>
        <p>Step 1</p>
      </div>
      <div class="stepwizard-step">
        <a href="#step-2" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle" disabled="disabled">2</a>
        <p>Step 2</p>
      </div>
      <div class="stepwizard-step">
        <a href="#step-3" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle" disabled="disabled">3</a>
        <p>Step 3</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <form role="form" action="" method="post">
    <div class="row setup-content" id="step-1">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <h3> Step 1</h3>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">First Name</label>
            <input  maxlength="100" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter First Name"  />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Last Name</label>
            <input maxlength="100" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Last Name" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Address</label>
            <textarea required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter your address" ></textarea>
          </div>
          <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-lg pull-right" type="button" >Next</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row setup-content" id="step-2">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <h3> Step 2</h3>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Company Name</label>
            <input maxlength="200" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Company Name" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Company Address</label>
            <input maxlength="200" type="text" required="required" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Company Address"  />
          </div>
          <button class="btn btn-primary nextBtn btn-lg pull-right" type="button" >Next</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row setup-content" id="step-3">
      <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-offset-3">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <h3> Step 3</h3>
          <button class="btn btn-success btn-lg pull-right" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Was it just me leaving out the references? Told you it was something stupid. Thanks...